# Android webview load Instagram URL but URL not changed

Tags: android, webview

I have a simple webview app that loads my website. Everything is ok, but when the user clicks on the Instagram icon in bottom of the webpage, I want to open the Instagram app instead of loading the Instagram webpage.

I'm trying to achieve this with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` function and `webview.geturl("https://www.instagram.com/")`.

The problem is when the user clicks on the Instagram icon, the URL doesn't change and stays default "http://archclub.ir/".

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("http://archclub.ir/login");
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            url = webView.getUrl();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, webView.getUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

             if (url.contains("https://www.instagram.com/")) {

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "salam", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                webView.loadUrl("http://archclub.ir/");

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

}}
```

My problem is: When the user clicks on the Instagram icon on the website, the `Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "salam", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` doesn't run.

I've checked this. I've debugged it. The problem is when the Instagram icon is clicked, the `webview.geturl` is equal to archclub.ir/login and doesn't change to instagram.com but the webview shows the Instagram page.

Comment: Probably because you're just telling it to load `http://archclub.ir/` again?

Comment: i check this....i had debug it ...the problem is when instagram icon clicked the webview.geturl is equals http://archclub.ir/login and dont change to instagram.com but webview shows instagram page

Comment: Don't you need to change the `webView.loadUrl("http://archclub.ir/");` to the correct url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were replacing the url over and over.
please replace this block of code instead of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method :

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
           // url = webView.getUrl();  // just omit this line

            Toast.makeText(ali.this, webView.getUrl(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            if (url.contains("https://www.instagram.com/")) {

                Toast.makeText(ali.this, "salam", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                webView.loadUrl("http://archclub.ir/");
                return true;


            } else return false;
        }


    });
```

Comment: unexpectedly it works wow ....but i don't understand what  couses the problem.... .....TNX BRO

Comment: @AliHooshmand this lined caused the problem : url = webView.getUrl();  your welcome. also don't forget to upvote the answer :D